# How to extract the stems out of multiple file paths using pathlib?

Tags: python, pathlib

I am trying to extract the stem out of multiple file paths using pathlib and failing to do so.

Here is the code I tried:

```
base_path = Path(__file__).parent
paths = (base_path / "../dictionary/files/").glob('**/*')
files = [x for x in paths if x.is_file()]
for i in range(len(files)):
     stem_name = files.stem[i]
```

Here is the error:

```
for i in range(len(files)):
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

I have text files with names as `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt`

Expected:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: @jezrael any idea on how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close.

You should be indexing `files` (which is the list), and then each element of the list (`files[i]`) would be a `<class 'pathlib.PosixPath'>` instance, which would have the `.stem` method.

```
for i in range(len(files)):
    stem_name = files[i].stem
```

```
(test-py38) gino:Q$ cat test.py
from pathlib import Path

base_path = Path(__file__).parent
paths = (base_path / "./files").glob('**/*')
files = [x for x in paths if x.is_file()]
for i in range(len(files)):
    stem_name = files[i].stem
    print(stem_name)

(test-py38) gino:Q$ ls files
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt

(test-py38) gino:Q$ python test.py
2
3
1
```

I'm not sure about this error though, because it is not reproducible from the posted code:

> ```
> for i in range(len(files)):
>     TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
> ```

This is only reproducible if you either used [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to create `files` or you used a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) (`files = (...)`) instead of a list comprehension (`files = [...]`). In both cases, you would be calling `len` on a generator, and that won't work because [generators don't support `len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators).

```
(test-py38) gino:Q$ cat test.py
from pathlib import Path

base_path = Path(__file__).parent
paths = (base_path / "./files").glob('**/*')
files = (x for x in paths if x.is_file())  # <---- generator expression
for i in range(len(files)):
    stem_name = files[i].stem
    print(stem_name)

(test-py38) gino:Q$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    for i in range(len(files)):
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

If you need to [loop through a generator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators), don't use indexing.

```
files = (x for x in paths if x.is_file())
for a_file in files:
    stem_name = a_file.stem
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for file_ in files:
    stem = file_.stem
    print(stem)
```